# ios: how to convert a NSString to int64_t?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to convert a `NSString` to `int64_t` and then print it out using:

```
NSLog("%lld", i);
```

Now I can only convert using `[str integerValue]` which sometimes makes it print out the minus number.

Comment: What is the content of the string? Integer? Float? Text?

Comment: How about [str longLongValue]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `atoll` function.

```
int64_t i = atoll([str UTF8String]);
```

Comment: What is the class of your `str` object if not `NSString`?!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[str longLongValue]`

For example:

```
int64_t i=[@"23570449442514" longLongValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

longLongValue works!
[str longLongValue];