# Gamecenter Score Not Submitting Correct Score

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

When I test my game the score of my game ends in a time of 3.49 seconds, but in gamecenter the score that shows up in the leaderboards is 1:01:52.76. I think the problem is that i get a yellow flag that says incompatible integer to integer conversion assigning to int_64 (aka long long) from NSString. Here is the part of the code that shows the error.

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self startTimer];

    count--;

    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];

    // 2

    if (count == 0) {

        [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];

        timeLabel.hidden = YES;



        // Create date from the elapsed time

        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];

        NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];



        // Create a date formatter

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'Your time: 'ss.SSS"];

        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];



        // Format the elapsed time and set it to the label

        NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];



        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"

                                                        message: timeString

                                                       delegate:self

                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"

                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Level Select",nil];



        [alert show];

        if (count == 0) {

            GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"tap_novice"];



            scoreReporter.value = timeString;



            scoreReporter.context = 0;



            NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];



            [GKScore reportScores:@[scoreReporter] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                if (error == nil) {

                    NSLog(@"Score reported successfully!");

                } else {

                    NSLog(@"Unable to report score!");

                }

            }];

        }

    }    

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the current line you have:

```
scoreReporter.value = timeString;
```

You should use:

```
int64_t timeAsInt = [timeString longLongValue];  
scoreReporter.value = timeAsInt;
```

See [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192105/ios-how-to-convert-a-nsstring-to-int64-t)